# readline not working properly

Tags: c, readline

When I run this code in Xcode, I get build failed. I got the chunk from The Big Nerd Ranch Guide to Obj-C. I had to modify it a little (added the libraries stdlib.h and readline/readline.h) It says the build failed, but there are no errors that I can see. This question may look like a duplicate, and in a way it is, but even after seeing their solutions and trying them for myself, I still get the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Who is cool? ");
    const char *name = readline(NULL);
    printf("%s is cool!\n\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_readline", referenced
>   from:
>         _main in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: On one hand you say "nothing happens" when you run it. But on the other hand you say the "build failed". Can you please clarify whether you are asking about a compile time or a run time problem?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! Wasn't thinking clearly. When I click run, it says build failed. Prior to that, and after, it says there are no errors.

Comment: When it says "build failed" there should be an error log. Please post the exact errors being reported. Also, have you linked in libreadline? You said you have "added the libraries". But those are headers used during compile time but not the actual libraries needed to link. I don't know anything about Xcode but somewhere you need to tell it to link in libreadline. On the command line it would be the `-lreadline` option.

Comment: I'm going to upload the console readout to the question in a few seconds.

Comment: the posted code is missing the call: `free(name);` before the `return 0;` statement

Comment: when compiling, Always enable all the warnings.  (for gcc, at a  minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic' )  Then fix the warnings.  Amongst other things, the posted code raises two warnings: parameter 'argc' is unused and parameter 'argv[]' is unused.

Comment: the error message you posted, is from the link step.  It indicates that either 1) your specific installation does not have the readline library.  or 2) your link step is missing the library path and/or the library  name parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar problem is mentioned in [this link](http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=139&t=7569). You  have to link the `libreadline.dylib` file to your project in the build phase.

Comment: This is one of the links I referenced for a fix, but it didn't solve my problem. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: Did you visit the Link Binary With Libraries section of the Build Phases and add libreadline.dylib and <stdio.h>? The error is relevant to this phase, I don't see why it shouldn't work after that.

Comment: Ah! I had no idea how to do that. I just looked it up and added it. It works fine now, only problem is that my input is doubled (ex. I enter Sam, it types out as SSaamm.) Anyway, thanks for the answer!